# Run jupyter notebook in background with no log on terminal

Tags: python, bash, terminal, jupyter-notebook

I am using jupyter notebook on a server and running it in the background using :

```
jupyter notebook &
```

however, this means that anything I do in the hosted folder will create a log on the terminal which interferes in my use of the terminal.

Is there a way to run jupyter notebook silently in the background and use the terminal normally?

Comment: You can use like a supervisor or systemd to launch the process in background and write the log's to a file in a specified location. And also it helps to launch whenever you restarted your system

Comment: @oguzismail no that didnt work at all. still getting logs on the terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

`nohup jupyter notebook &`

Comment: This works, but stores everything to `nohup.out`. Leaving it open for a while to see something that skips that too

Comment: @fireball.1 Have you tried `man nohup`? "To  save  output  to  FILE,  use 'nohup COMMAND > FILE'."